# How to share game's record on facebook

Tags: java, android, facebook

i want to enable my app users to share their records on facebook, how can i do so? i donwloaded the facebook sdk but i cannot find a proper guide..

i tried sharing it via an intent like

```
btShare.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=g.d.squarememory");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share..."));
        }
    });
```

but

1° it doesn't share the text and link i want
2° i'd like a text next to the logo of my app

have you got any idea?

Answer (score 1):

try this, this is a very good tutorial for facebook android integration                [facebook android integration](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-facebook-connect-tutorial/)